# Jasmine, Phantom and Team city cannot running tests on team city

Tags: jasmine, teamcity, phantomjs

I am using Jasmine 2.0 with requirejs based application, where i can able to run test suites on the browser. But when i tried to configure with the team city. I am getting the following error.

From build log

Starting: E:\APPS\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\12a3bd79c15e632f\Web.UnitTests\phantomjs.exe E:\APPS\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\12a3bd79c15e632f\Web.UnitTests\run-jasmine.js E:\APPS\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\12a3bd79c15e632f\Web.UnitTests\SpecRunner.html
    [17:00:25]in directory: E:\APPS\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\12a3bd79c15e632f
    [17:00:30]'waitFor()' finished in 2001ms.
    [17:00:30]TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.body.querySelector('.alert > .bar.passed').innerText')
    [17:00:30]
    [17:00:30]  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():58
    [17:00:30]  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():61
    [17:00:30]  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():61
    [17:00:30]Process exited with code 0

When i separately run tests in cmd, I was getting same error. After increased wait time in run-jasmine.js tests were run successsfully.
The problem i am facing is that regradless of wait time when running teamcity i getting the above errors.

I have place code here https://github.com/Purush0th/jasmine_ci

Comment: My problem is different i have checked the mentioned duplication link... I am using the same run-jasmine still am getting error. Here see my comment https://gist.github.com/barahilia/9663804

Comment: Then you should have included all information in the question including that the duplicated question didn't work. Please edit your question accordingly.